# Request hangs on upload using multer when wrapped inside another function

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload image using `multer` and `multers3`. I have wrapped the multer's upload inside another function. Instead of calling `multer` direcly. This function is called. like below.

**FileHandler.js**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('something.digitaloceanspaces.com'),
  accessKeyId: 'something',
  secretAccessKey: 'something'
});


var spacesHandler = function(){
    // Configure client for use with Spaces
    this.s3 = new AWS.S3();
}
spacesHandler.prototype.uploadFiles = function (req, res, cb) {
    var self = this;
    // var item = req.body;
    var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: self.s3,
            bucket: 'prod.bucket1'  /*req.params.bucketName*/,
            acl: 'public-read',
            contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
            metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
            },
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, Date.now().toString()+'-'+file.originalname)
            }
        })
    }).single();
    upload(req, res, cb);
};
```

So, this file return a constructor funciton. Which has `uploadFiles` method on it's prototype.
*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');

var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

var logger = require('morgan');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var upload = require('./DO-Spaces-Plugin/FileHandler'); //upload is a constructor here

upload = new upload; // upload is a new object here which has uplodFiles method on its protoype

var app = express();


app.use(upload.uploadFiles, function(req, res){

  return res.send('File uploaded!')

});
```

It's not working, request is hanging to `uploadFiles`. 
*I think there is something with the callback inside uploadFiles.*

`cb` is like next here which is being passed to `upload(req, res, cb)`.
I think request is not being passed to next middleware (route handler funciton). 
I will appreciate any kind of help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `this` context, you probably need to define that context instead of just passing the reference to the function.

```js
app.use(upload.uploadFiles.bind(upload), ...
```

Another way, in your case, would be to *return* the wrapped `upload` function:

```js
app.use(upload.uploadFiles(), ... // notice we _call_ the function here

// in your middleware file, last line of spacesHandler.prototype.uploadFiles:
return upload; // notice we _return_ the function _itself_ (i.e. not called, so this _is_ our middleware)
```